# end of the file expected in json format vscode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

```
 { // For example, the files explorer decides which files and folders to show 
    // or hide based on this setting. 
    // Read more about glob patterns [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options).

    "files.exclude": {
      "**/.git": true,
      "**/.svn": true,
      "**/.hg": true,
      "**/CVS": true,
      "**/.DS_Store": true
    },
  
    // Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in searches. 
    // Inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting.   
    // Read more about glob patterns [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options).
    "search.exclude": {
      "**/node_modules": true,
      "**/bower_components": true
    },
    // Configure glob patterns of file paths to exclude from file watching. 
    // Patterns must match on absolute paths 
    // (i.e. prefix with ** or the full path to match properly). 
    // Changing this setting requires a restart. 
    // When you experience Code consuming lots of cpu time on startup, 
    // you can exclude large folders to reduce the initial load.
    "files.watcherExclude": {
      "**/.git/objects/**": true,
      "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
      "**/node_modules/*/**": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?  Is that the error you are getting from vscode?  There is nothing wrong  with your settings file as you showed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.